# How to justify div children using flex

Tags: css

I need to align two row this way:

```html
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content:space-between;">
  <div>
    <span>Color</span> ----------- <span>Blue</span>
    <span>Model</span> ----------- <span>2019</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Color</span> ----------- <span>Black</span>
    <span>Model</span> ----------- <span>2019</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried using:

```
display:flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content:space-between;
```

But it doesn't work.
How can I justify using space between ?

Comment: `I need to align two row this way`. Which way? Can you give example or screenshot

Comment: there is no height to have the div justified inside the column.

Comment: Note that only **direct** children of the flexbox container(the element which has `display` set to `flex`) are considered as flex items. So in your current code, you have actually just two flex items which are of type `div` and `span` elements are not considered a flex item.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want in this way :

```
<div style="display:flex;" >
  <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content:space-between;">
    <span>Color</span> ----------- <span>Blue</span>
    <span>Model</span> ----------- <span>2019</span>
  </div>
  <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content:space-between;">
    <span>Color</span> ----------- <span>Black</span>
    <span>Model</span> ----------- <span>2019</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Want this way ?

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div><span>Color</span> ----------- <span>Blue</span>
    <span>Model</span> ----------- <span>2019</span></div>
  <div><span>Color</span> ----------- <span>Black</span>
    <span>Model</span> ----------- <span>2019</span></div>

</div>
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex; 
   justify-content:space-between;
}
```

[image]